# Upgrading Laravel To 5.5.0 From 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Actually, when I want to upgrade my version of Laravel I face to this problem, so any body have any answer to help me in this case.

Problem 1

```
This package requires php >=7.0.0 but your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Problem 2

```
- laravel/framework v5.5.9 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.8 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.7 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.6 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.5 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.4 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.32 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.31 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.30 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.3 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.29 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.28 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.27 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.26 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.25 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.24 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.23 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.22 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.21 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.20 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.2 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.19 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.18 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.17 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.16 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.15 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.14 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.13 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.12 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.11 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.10 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.1 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v5.5.0 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.29, v5.5.3, v5.5.30, v5.5.31, v5.5.32, v5.5.4, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9].
```

When I checked my Php version in wamp server the version is 7.1.9 but I don't know when I want to update my laravel project I face to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the solution. when I was install the Wamp server 3.1.0, so in this directory C:\wamp64\bin\php I found three folder php5.6.31, php7.0.23, php7.1.9 and with one notepad which mentioned don't delete the folder of php5.6.31, so when I want to change the Php version from wamp it show the Php version is php7.1.9, but when I check through the Cmd. it show the version of php is php5.6.31, and I was unable to upgrade my laravel version.

Soultion:

first go to Computer->Properties-> Advance System Settings-> Advance Option-> Environment variable-> system variable ->find Path and edit remove the path of php5.6.31 and add new path of php7.1.9 from C:\wamp64\bin\php just restart wamp server or even it doesn't work uninstall it again install and through wamp serve select Php version you want,and change it the after selecting the version you can check through Cmd and type php -version, the new version of Php will appear, so finally you can upgrade the version of your laravel.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You likely have two php installations. Check your filesystem and remove the old version. It's clearly using 5.6.

Comment: From where? From wamp server this address C:\wamp64\bin\php I have three folder of php with these version php5.6.31, php7.0.23, php7.1.9  when I delete this one php5.6.31 wamp serve give error and it not working.

Comment: Well that is the version referenced in the logs you posted so that's the one you should delete. Wamp needs to be updated to use a newer version of php it sounds like. There's likely a configuration file somewhere that's just needs updated.